# Fullscreen Video in Webview is not working in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am using https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappbrowser to display a webview in my app. The video on the website is playing but not displaying in fullscreen even when the fullscreen button is pressed.

Is there a way to display a video in fullscreen in a webview?

Comment: I think that's not fixed now.

Comment: do you get any solution?

Comment: @GaneshKrishnamoorthy No, still trying :(

Comment: you have to override showcustom method in web chrome client class. Then the square icon (fullscreen) will be enabled. After that, you write your own code to make the full screen of your webview in flutter using a callback

Answer (score 2):

This should work with [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter). But it seems that there is some [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67791).

I have reproduced the issue using this sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: "https://youtube.com/",
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

But it worked in a different approach which uses "[flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)" formerly known as "[flutter_inappbrowser](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappbrowser)". Using the current [Flutter InAppWebView Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) will make videos with full screen capability to be enabled.

Here is a working sample code using YouTube:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController _webViewController;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text(
                "CURRENT URL\n${(url.length > 50) ? url.substring(0, 50) + "..." : url}"),
          ),
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: progress < 1.0
                  ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress)
                  : Container()),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
              child: InAppWebView(
                initialUrl: "https://youtube.com/",
                initialHeaders: {},
                initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                  debuggingEnabled: true,
                )),
                onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                  _webViewController = controller;
                },
                onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.url = url;
                  });
                },
                onLoadStop:
                    (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
                  setState(() {
                    this.url = url;
                  });
                },
                onProgressChanged:
                    (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.progress = progress / 100;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_webViewController != null) {
                    _webViewController.goBack();
                  }
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_webViewController != null) {
                    _webViewController.goForward();
                  }
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_webViewController != null) {
                    _webViewController.reload();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Sample output:
[image]

Full-screen mode:
[image]

Comment: hi thanks for you answer, is it possible to customize the full screen size or just put a container above the full screen youtube video?