# I want to convert html game to flutter android app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, game-development

I used package webview_flutter and worked perfectly my problem I want to load just the game in full screen mobile (in my case webview loaded all screen content)

Comment: You can get the link of the game from the web page and give that link to the webview widget

Comment: Yes, That's what I did and worked, but a don't display in my app the header site  footer.... I want just the part game

Comment: You can fetch a specific div element from the HTML file in dart and render the fetched HTML locally in webview. Heres the said approach (Not a flutter solution) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40497702/8253662

Comment: Heres how to render a local html file in flutter webview https://stackoverflow.com/a/55149298/8253662

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is similar to showing full-screen a video on a webview_flutter .

You can get help from the following link.

[Sample Using WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237533/fullscreen-video-in-webview-is-not-working-in-flutter)